# mysql: Show GRANTs for all users

Tags: mysql, permissions

MySQL's [`SHOW GRANTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html) shows the permissions of the current user.

Is there a way to log in as root and show the permissions of all users?

Comment: this post has nice workaround : https://dbadiaries.com/no-mysql-show-users-how-to-list-mysql-user-accounts-and-their-privileges

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Nothing built-in. You have two options though:

- Use `common_schema`'s [sql_show_grants](https://shlomi-noach.github.io/common_schema/sql_show_grants.html) view. For example, you can query:

  ```sql
  SELECT sql_grants FROM common_schema.sql_show_grants;
  ```

  Or you can query for particular users, for example:

  ```sql
  SELECT sql_grants FROM common_schema.sql_show_grants WHERE user='app';
  ```

  To install `common_schema`, follow the instructions [here](http://shlomi-noach.github.io/common_schema/install.html).

  Disclaimer: I am author of this tool.
- Use Percona Toolkit's [`pt-show-grants`](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-show-grants.html), for example:

  ```
  pt-show-grants --host localhost --user root --ask-pass
  ```

In both cases you can ask for the `GRANT` command or the `REVOKE` (opposite) command.

The first case requires that you install a schema, the latter requires that you install PERL scripts + dependencies.

Comment: +1 for developing this tool! Any chance that MySQL will adopt your code?

Comment: Many thanks! I'm pushing this project at this time (new release scheduled in a week or so), in an attempt to make it popular. I do not know if any will adopt it.

Comment: I am going to stop working on my answer. It looks like you are light-years ahead on this one. +1. I hope it gains more traction in the MySQL Universe.

Comment: Could you please describe in more detail how to use common_schema's sql_show_grants view? I get an error `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'common_schema.sql_show_grants' doesn't exist`

Comment: @MartinVegter , have you installed common_schema? Download [here](http://code.google.com/p/common-schema/downloads/list) and install [following these instructions](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/install.html).

Comment: @ShlomiNoach, When you say that there's "nothing built-in"... Are there any errors with [`information_schema.user_privileges`](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/62638/9405)?

Comment: @Pacerier please see my comment on the `user_privileges` answer

Comment: Uhh, It looks like this `common_schema` select will truncate data at 1024 characters :(

Comment: @ThorSummoner, it is unfortunate that the MySQL's default value for `group_concat_max_len` is 1024. It is one of the first defaults to change, and I recommend that you set it to a high value such as `1,000,000` or above. See further in [my blog](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/those-oversized-undersized-variables-defaults)

Comment: please see this question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/155355/is-common-schema-safe

Comment: @ThorSummoner that's your `group_concat_max_len` setting limitation. `SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=1000000` to solve. Also of course in config file.

Comment: ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'common_schema.sql_show_grants' doesn't exist

Comment: The tool doesn't install properly on MySQL 5.7: it throws an error around line 197

Comment: Sorry, but there's no such thing as a 'common_schema'.  It doesn't exist.

Comment: link sql_show_grants  broken

Comment: @BrendanByrd: It is a 3rd party tool, that used to be hosted on Google Code... (I'm not sure what the official replacement repo is)

Answer (score 125):

```
select * from information_schema.user_privileges;
```

EDIT:

As mentioned by Shlomi Noach:

> It does not list database-specific, table-specific, column-specific,
>   routine-specific privileges. Therefore, the grant GRANT SELECT ON
>   mydb.* TO myuser@localhost does not show in
>   information_schema.user_privileges. The common_schema solution
>   presented above aggregates the data from user_privileges and other tables
>   to give you the full picture.

Comment: Sorry, it should not be the accepted answer. `information_schema.user_privileges` only lists user-level privileges, such as `SUPER`, `RELOAD` etc. It also lists all-round DML grants like `SELECT`. It does *not* list database-specific, table-sepcific, column-specific, routine-specific privileges. There fore, the grant `GRANT SELECT ON mydb.* TO myuser@localhost` does *not* show on `information_schema.user_privileges`. The `common_schema` solution presented above aggregates data from `user_privileges` and other tables to give you the full picture.

Comment: The `common_schema` does not exist on the official MySQL table set, so I disagree with taking away the checkmark here.  Not everybody has access to install custom databases like that.

Comment: Best short answer and should be the accepted one.

Comment: Now I wish this table was in first normal form ...

Answer (score 21):

This Linux shell fragment loops over all MySQL users and does a [SHOW GRANTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html) for each:

```
mysql --silent --skip-column-names --execute "select concat('\'',User,'\'@\'',Host,'\'') as User from mysql.user" | sort | \
while read u
 do echo "-- $u"; mysql --silent --skip-column-names --execute "show grants for $u" | sed 's/$/;/'
done
```

Works best if you can connect to MySQL without a password.

Output is formatted so it can be run in a MySQL shell.
Caution: Output also contains the MySQL root user permissions and password! Remove those lines if you don't want the MySQL root user changed.

Comment: You may want to add some details about what this does or how it answers the question.  Just displaying a bunch of code doesn't help anyone understand why your solution works.

Comment: Where can I give password?

Comment: To provide a password one may use a [Option File](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html) or the [--password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_password) flag of the mysql command.

Comment: Would it not be possible to give one root password and run the query to get all users grants?

Comment: Youd could ask for the password and store it in a variable with something like bash's `read`, then use `--password=$STORED_PW`. But this is [considered insecure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-security-user.html).

Comment: You can stream the requests in order to make only one connection, and use a mode 400 root-owned credentials file. My version: `mysql --defaults-file=/auth/root-mysql.cnf --batch --skip-column-names --execute "SELECT User, Host from mysql.user" | while read user host; do echo "SHOW GRANTS FOR '${user}'@'${host}';"; done | mysql --defaults-file=/auth/root-mysql.cnf --batch | sed 's/^Grants for/-- Grants for/'`

Answer (score 12):

One liner (change `-uroot` to `-u$USER_NAME` for use with other user) in a Unix bash (because of the backticks):

```
mysql -uroot -p -sNe"`mysql -uroot -p -se"SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR \'',user,'\'@\'',host,'\';') FROM mysql.user;"`"
```

or without backticks and with password inline (space in front of command excludes it from Bash history in Ubuntu):

```
 mysql -uroot -p"$PASSWORD" -sNe"$(mysql -uroot -p"$PASSWORD" -se"SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR \'',user,'\'@\'',host,'\';') FROM mysql.user;")"
```

In Windows:

```
mysql -uroot -p -se"SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR \'',user,'\'@\'',host,'\';') FROM mysql.user;" > grants.sql
mysql -uroot -p < grants.sql
del grants.sql
```

Answer (score 10):

If you can run the following SELECT statements *without* error:

```sql
/* User-Specific Grants     */   SELECT * FROM mysql.user;
/* Database-Specific Grants */   SELECT * FROM mysql.db;
/* Table-Specific Grants    */   SELECT * FROM mysql.tables_priv;
/* Column-Specific Grants   */   SELECT * FROM mysql.columns_priv;
```

then feel free to use the below `MySQL Grant Rebuilder` script to expedite getting user permissions from a MySQL server.

- I designed this query in an attempt to re-build `GRANT` statements for all existing permissions (for frequent upkeep during database migration).
- There are a few issues to be handeld, such as user-password-linking, but because we frequently update passwords, that was not in the scope of this project.

#### *Edit (01-Aug-2023)*

- Updated the `MySQL Grant Rebuilder` script (below) to the latest version I ended up with before taking a position at a different company (which didn't use `MySQL` at any capacity).
- Adding a link to the script on GitHub: [`MySQL - Reverse Engineer MySQL Grants.sql`](https://github.com/mcavallo-git/Coding/blob/main/mysql/MySQL%20-%20Reverse%20Engineer%20MySQL%20Grants.sql)

## MySQL Grant Rebuilder <sub>*(Reverse Engineer Grants)*</sub>

```sql
SET @SPECIFIC_USER := ''; /* If blank, show all user grants, otherwise show only target user's grants */

/* Column-Specific Grants */
SELECT
  gcl.User AS 'User-Account(s) Affected',
  IF(gcl.Host='%',"ALL",gcl.Host) AS 'Remote-IP(s) Affected',
  CONCAT("`",gcl.Db,"`") AS 'Database(s) Affected',
  CONCAT("`",gcl.Table_name,"`") AS 'Table(s) Affected',
  CONCAT(UPPER(gcl.Column_priv)," (",GROUP_CONCAT(gcl.Column_name ORDER BY UPPER(gcl.Column_name) SEPARATOR ", "),") ") AS 'Column(s) Affected',
  CONCAT("GRANT ",UPPER(gcl.Column_priv)," (",
          GROUP_CONCAT(gcl.Column_name ORDER BY UPPER(gcl.Column_name)),") ",
         "ON `",gcl.Db,"`.`",gcl.Table_name,"` ",
         "TO '",gcl.User,"'@'",gcl.Host,"';") AS 'GRANT Statement (Reconstructed)',
  CONCAT_WS(", ","SERVER","DATABASE","TABLE","COLUMN") AS 'Scope',
  NOW() AS 'Timestamp'
FROM `mysql`.columns_priv gcl
WHERE true
AND (gcl.User=@SPECIFIC_USER OR 'show_all'=(IF(@SPECIFIC_USER<>'','single_user','show_all')))
GROUP BY CONCAT(gcl.Host,gcl.Db,gcl.User,gcl.Table_name,gcl.Column_priv)
/* SELECT * FROM `mysql`.columns_priv */

UNION

/* Table-Specific Grants */
SELECT
  gtb.User AS 'User-Account(s) Affected',
  IF(gtb.Host='%',"ALL",gtb.Host) AS 'Remote-IP(s) Affected',
  CONCAT("`",gtb.Db,"`") AS 'Database(s) Affected',
  CONCAT("`",gtb.Table_name,"`") AS 'Table(s) Affected',
  "ALL" AS 'Column(s) Affected',
  CONCAT(
    "GRANT ",UPPER(gtb.Table_priv)," ",
    "ON `",gtb.Db,"`.`",gtb.Table_name,"` ",
    "TO '",gtb.User,"'@'",gtb.Host,"';"
  ) AS 'GRANT Statement (Reconstructed)',
  CONCAT_WS(", ","SERVER","DATABASE","TABLE") AS 'Scope',
  NOW() AS 'Timestamp'
FROM `mysql`.tables_priv gtb
WHERE gtb.Table_priv!=''
AND (gtb.User=@SPECIFIC_USER OR 'show_all'=(IF(@SPECIFIC_USER<>'','single_user','show_all')))
/* SELECT * FROM `mysql`.tables_priv */

UNION

/* Database-Specific Grants */
SELECT
  gdb.User AS 'User-Account(s) Affected',
  IF(gdb.Host='%',"ALL",gdb.Host) AS 'Remote-IP(s) Affected',
  CONCAT("`",gdb.Db,"`") AS 'Database(s) Affected',
  "ALL" AS 'Table(s) Affected',
  "ALL" AS 'Column(s) Affected',
  CONCAT(
    'GRANT ',
    CONCAT_WS(',',
      IF(gdb.Select_priv='Y','SELECT',NULL),
      IF(gdb.Insert_priv='Y','INSERT',NULL),
      IF(gdb.Update_priv='Y','UPDATE',NULL),
      IF(gdb.Delete_priv='Y','DELETE',NULL),
      IF(gdb.Create_priv='Y','CREATE',NULL),
      IF(gdb.Drop_priv='Y','DROP',NULL),
      IF(gdb.Grant_priv='Y','GRANT',NULL),
      IF(gdb.References_priv='Y','REFERENCES',NULL),
      IF(gdb.Index_priv='Y','INDEX',NULL),
      IF(gdb.Alter_priv='Y','ALTER',NULL),
      IF(gdb.Create_tmp_table_priv='Y','CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES',NULL),
      IF(gdb.Lock_tables_priv='Y','LOCK TABLES',NULL),
      IF(gdb.Create_view_priv='Y','CREATE VIEW',NULL),
      IF(gdb.Show_view_priv='Y','SHOW VIEW',NULL),
      IF(gdb.Create_routine_priv='Y','CREATE ROUTINE',NULL),
      IF(gdb.Alter_routine_priv='Y','ALTER ROUTINE',NULL),
      IF(gdb.Execute_priv='Y','EXECUTE',NULL),
      IF(gdb.Event_priv='Y','EVENT',NULL),
      IF(gdb.Trigger_priv='Y','TRIGGER',NULL)
    ),
    " ON `",gdb.Db,"`.* TO '",gdb.User,"'@'",gdb.Host,"';"
  ) AS 'GRANT Statement (Reconstructed)',
  CONCAT_WS(", ","SERVER","DATABASE") AS 'Scope',
  NOW() AS 'Timestamp'
FROM `mysql`.db gdb
WHERE gdb.Db != ''
AND (gdb.User=@SPECIFIC_USER OR 'show_all'=(IF(@SPECIFIC_USER<>'','single_user','show_all')))
/* SELECT * FROM `mysql`.db */

UNION

/* User-Specific Grants */
SELECT
  usr.User AS 'User-Account(s) Affected',
  IF(usr.Host='%',"ALL",usr.Host) AS 'Remote-IP(s) Affected',
  "ALL" AS 'Database(s) Affected',
  "ALL" AS 'Table(s) Affected',
  "ALL" AS 'Column(s) Affected',
  CONCAT(
    "GRANT ",
    IF((usr.Select_priv='N')&(usr.Insert_priv='N')&(usr.Update_priv='N')&(usr.Delete_priv='N')&(usr.Create_priv='N')&(usr.Drop_priv='N')&(usr.Reload_priv='N')&(usr.Shutdown_priv='N')&(usr.Process_priv='N')&(usr.File_priv='N')&(usr.References_priv='N')&(usr.Index_priv='N')&(usr.Alter_priv='N')&(usr.Show_db_priv='N')&(usr.Super_priv='N')&(usr.Create_tmp_table_priv='N')&(usr.Lock_tables_priv='N')&(usr.Execute_priv='N')&(usr.Repl_slave_priv='N')&(usr.Repl_client_priv='N')&(usr.Create_view_priv='N')&(usr.Show_view_priv='N')&(usr.Create_routine_priv='N')&(usr.Alter_routine_priv='N')&(usr.Create_user_priv='N')&(usr.Event_priv='N')&(usr.Trigger_priv='N')&(usr.Create_tablespace_priv='N')&(usr.Grant_priv='N'),
      "USAGE",
      IF((usr.Select_priv='Y')&(usr.Insert_priv='Y')&(usr.Update_priv='Y')&(usr.Delete_priv='Y')&(usr.Create_priv='Y')&(usr.Drop_priv='Y')&(usr.Reload_priv='Y')&(usr.Shutdown_priv='Y')&(usr.Process_priv='Y')&(usr.File_priv='Y')&(usr.References_priv='Y')&(usr.Index_priv='Y')&(usr.Alter_priv='Y')&(usr.Show_db_priv='Y')&(usr.Super_priv='Y')&(usr.Create_tmp_table_priv='Y')&(usr.Lock_tables_priv='Y')&(usr.Execute_priv='Y')&(usr.Repl_slave_priv='Y')&(usr.Repl_client_priv='Y')&(usr.Create_view_priv='Y')&(usr.Show_view_priv='Y')&(usr.Create_routine_priv='Y')&(usr.Alter_routine_priv='Y')&(usr.Create_user_priv='Y')&(usr.Event_priv='Y')&(usr.Trigger_priv='Y')&(usr.Create_tablespace_priv='Y')&(usr.Grant_priv='Y'),
        "ALL PRIVILEGES",
        CONCAT_WS(',',
          IF(usr.Select_priv='Y','SELECT',NULL),
          IF(usr.Insert_priv='Y','INSERT',NULL),
          IF(usr.Update_priv='Y','UPDATE',NULL),
          IF(usr.Delete_priv='Y','DELETE',NULL),
          IF(usr.Create_priv='Y','CREATE',NULL),
          IF(usr.Drop_priv='Y','DROP',NULL),
          IF(usr.Reload_priv='Y','RELOAD',NULL),
          IF(usr.Shutdown_priv='Y','SHUTDOWN',NULL),
          IF(usr.Process_priv='Y','PROCESS',NULL),
          IF(usr.File_priv='Y','FILE',NULL),
          IF(usr.References_priv='Y','REFERENCES',NULL),
          IF(usr.Index_priv='Y','INDEX',NULL),
          IF(usr.Alter_priv='Y','ALTER',NULL),
          IF(usr.Show_db_priv='Y','SHOW DATABASES',NULL),
          IF(usr.Super_priv='Y','SUPER',NULL),
          IF(usr.Create_tmp_table_priv='Y','CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES',NULL),
          IF(usr.Lock_tables_priv='Y','LOCK TABLES',NULL),
          IF(usr.Execute_priv='Y','EXECUTE',NULL),
          IF(usr.Repl_slave_priv='Y','REPLICATION SLAVE',NULL),
          IF(usr.Repl_client_priv='Y','REPLICATION CLIENT',NULL),
          IF(usr.Create_view_priv='Y','CREATE VIEW',NULL),
          IF(usr.Show_view_priv='Y','SHOW VIEW',NULL),
          IF(usr.Create_routine_priv='Y','CREATE ROUTINE',NULL),
          IF(usr.Alter_routine_priv='Y','ALTER ROUTINE',NULL),
          IF(usr.Create_user_priv='Y','CREATE USER',NULL),
          IF(usr.Event_priv='Y','EVENT',NULL),
          IF(usr.Trigger_priv='Y','TRIGGER',NULL),
          IF(usr.Create_tablespace_priv='Y','CREATE TABLESPACE',NULL)
        )
      )
    ),
    " ON *.* TO '",usr.User,"'@'",usr.Host,"' REQUIRE ",
    CASE usr.ssl_type
      WHEN 'ANY' THEN
        "SSL "
      WHEN 'X509' THEN
        "X509 "
      WHEN 'SPECIFIED' THEN
        CONCAT_WS("AND ",
          IF((LENGTH(usr.ssl_cipher)>0),CONCAT("CIPHER '",CONVERT(usr.ssl_cipher USING utf8),"' "),NULL),
          IF((LENGTH(usr.x509_issuer)>0),CONCAT("ISSUER '",CONVERT(usr.ssl_cipher USING utf8),"' "),NULL),
          IF((LENGTH(usr.x509_subject)>0),CONCAT("SUBJECT '",CONVERT(usr.ssl_cipher USING utf8),"' "),NULL)
        )
      ELSE "NONE "
    END,
    "WITH ",
    IF(usr.Grant_priv='Y',"GRANT OPTION ",""),
    "MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR ",usr.max_questions," ",
    "MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR ",usr.max_connections," ",
    "MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR ",usr.max_updates," ",
    "MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS ",usr.max_user_connections,
    ";"
  ) AS 'GRANT Statement (Reconstructed)',
  CONCAT_WS(", ","SERVER") AS 'Scope',
  NOW() AS 'Timestamp'
FROM `mysql`.user usr
-- WHERE usr.Password != '' /* MySQL 5.6- */
WHERE usr.authentication_string != '' /* MySQL 5.7+ */
AND (usr.User=@SPECIFIC_USER OR 'show_all'=(IF(@SPECIFIC_USER<>'','single_user','show_all')))

/* SELECT * FROM `mysql`.user usr */

  /* To-Do (1): Show User-Permissions
  /* SELECT * FROM information_schema.user_privileges privs */

  /* To-Do (2): Function Specific Grants ? */
  /* SELECT * FROM `mysql`.procs_priv gpr */

  /* To-Do (3): Procedure/Routine-Specific Grants*/
  /* SELECT * FROM `mysql`.procs_priv gpr */

  /* To-Do (4): ??? Host-Specific Grants ??? */
  /* SELECT * FROM `mysql`.host ghs */
```

Happy to answer / verify any questions or concerns

Comment: I know this is not kosher, but... your script is amazing! Now, all I have to do is to automate it. I'll warm up my bash

Comment: it is very amazing

Comment: @hanzo2001 I hope this proved useful in automation!

Comment: @Alex Thanks! Tons of time went into it, lol. I have a handful of other MySQL scripts that I've generalized - They can be seen [over on GitHub](https://github.com/mcavallo-git/Coding/tree/main/mysql). Maybe you'll get some use out of them, probably not but who knows!

Answer (score 9):

`select * from mysql.user;`

Can give you User list and Privileges assigned to each of them, requires access to `mysql.user` table though and `root` user has it.

Comment: This only gives you the "top level" (server level) privileges. Privileges set on specific schemas are in `mysql.db`. Privileges on specific tables are in `mysql.tables_priv`, and so on. So it's not so simple.

Comment: For rainbow table shenanigans, throw your password hashes from `select * from mysql.user` into https://crackstation.net and see the unhashed output.

Answer (score 5):

This will give you a better view...

```
mysql> select Host, Db, User, Insert_priv, Update_priv, Delete_priv, Create_tmp_table_priv, Alter_priv from mysql.db limit 1;
+------+------+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------+------------+
| Host | Db   | User | Insert_priv | Update_priv | Delete_priv | Create_tmp_table_priv | Alter_priv |
+------+------+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------+------------+
| %    | test |      | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y                     | Y          |
+------+------+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This is the best answer as of now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/399875/205506), you can run the following set of commands to list the database-specific, table-specific, column-specific and routine-specific privileges of all users. Note that you need to run this from the shell, not the MySQL command prompt.

```
mysql -u root --skip-column-names -A -e"SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ''',user,'''@''',host,''';') FROM mysql.user WHERE user<>''" | mysql -u root --skip-column-names -A
```

The advantage of this approach is that you don't need to install additional software.

Answer (score 1):

The command `SHOW GRANTS [FOR user]` may show any user you want. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you are administering databases often, you will likely want to keep tight privileges. You can use a stored procedure to quickly run a check. This example works in mariadb might need a tweak to work with the standard mysql version.

Using the answer from Mansur Ali with a little tweak reordering the columns and adding in some ordering to better organise the output.

Using a root login:

```
USE mysql;
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE ShowPrivs(start, end)
BEGIN
    SELECT Db, User, Host, Insert_priv, Update_priv, Delete_priv, Create_tmp_table_priv, Alter_priv FROM mysql.db order by Db, Host, User ASC;
END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

You could change the procedure to check mysql.user table instead.

Usage, using a root login:

```
USE mysql;
CALL ShowPrivs();
```

I used mysql workbench on Ubuntu to run the create procedure part of this answer.

As an aside and a little off the topic here but, you could also have a procedure to show unknown hosts or users. An example for unknown hosts:

```
USE mysql;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `ShowUnknownHosts`(IN Hosts_String VARCHAR(200))
BEGIN
    SELECT user,host FROM user
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(host, Hosts_String) = 0;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Usage note: Supply a string of hosts separated by commas so only one set of '' is used:

```
CALL ShowUnknownHosts('knownhost1,knownhost2');
```

You could also make the column variable by including another parameter in the procedure and call it with ShowUnknownHosts(user,'user1,user2'); for example.